# using jquery resize html objects with dynamically generated id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

There are many images in the page and I have the following php code in which the id of the images are generated dynamically

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value='.$count.'';
    for($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        echo '<input type="image" src= "image.png" id=img'.($i).'';
    }
```

Now, I have to resize these images one by one when they are double clicked. The code for that is as below

```
$function(){
    var c= document.getElementById('count').value;
    for(i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
        $('#V' + i).dblclick( function() {
            alert("Proceed with resizing");
            $('#V' + i).resizable();
        }
    });
```

With the above code,if the count is say 2 then it is showing alert twice but resizing one i.e the first one and the other one is not getting resized.

Comment: You did not close your input tags.

Comment: In input tag please enclose id value with inverted comma.
Eg: id="img";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this (you need jQuery for it)

```
$( 'input[type=image]' ).dblclick(function() {
    alert("Proceed with resizing");
    $(this).resizable();
});
```

This will target only element you are clicking on. You don't need to loop over all elements, the `dblclick` is an event, that is handled only when you are using it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
$(document).on('dblclick', "input[type='image']", function(){
     //alert('abc');  
    $(this).resizable();
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yub3k7mr/)

Comment: @areim.. resizable is working with ($this).resizable(). but draggable is not working with ($this).draggable(); . What should be done to make the images both draggable and resizable.